# Apply an gawk script to multiple files in a folder

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to use the following awk line to remove every even line (and keep the odd lines) in a text file.

```
awk 'NR%2==1' filename.txt > output
```

The problem is that I struggle to either loop properly in awk or build a shell script to apply this to all *.txt fies in a folder.  I tried to use this one-liner

```
gawk 'FNR==1{if(o)close(o);o=FILENAME;
sub(/\.txt/,"_oddlines.txt",o)}{NR%2==1; print>o}'
```

but that didn't remove the even lines. And I am even less familiar with shell scripting. I use `gawk` under `win7` or `cygwin` with `bash`. Many thanks for any kind of idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use

```
for filename in *.txt; do
    awk 'NR%2==1' "$filename" > "oddlines-$filename"
done
```

EDIT: quote filenames

Comment: thanks it works but I solved the issue with an awk script already. Tried yours as well and will use it in the future.

Comment: Won't select the odd numbered lines in each file and will fail cryptically for various file names.

Comment: updated for 'various file names' issue, but Ed Morton is wrong on the first issue

Answer (score 3):

Your existing gawk one-liner is **really close**.  Here it is formatted as a more readable script:

```
FNR == 1 {
    if (o)
        close(o)
    o = FILENAME
    sub(/\.txt/, "_oddlines.txt", o)
}
{
    NR % 2 == 1
    print > o
}
```

This should make the error obvious<sup>1</sup>.  So now we remove that error:

```
FNR == 1 {
    if (o)
        close(o)
    o = FILENAME
    sub(/\.txt/, "_oddlines.txt", o)
}
NR % 2 == 1 {
    print > o
}

$ awk -f foo.awk *.txt
```

and it works (and of course you can re-one-line-ize this).

(Normally I would do this with a `for` like the other answers, but I wanted to show you how close you were!)

---

<sup>1</sup>Per comment, maybe not quite so obvious?

Awk's basic language construct is the "pattern-action" statement.  An awk *program* is just a list of such statements.  The "pattern" is so named because originally they were mostly grep-like regular expression patterns:

```
$ awk '/^be.*st$/' < /usr/share/dict/web2
beanfeast
beast
[snip]
```

(Except for the slashes, this is basically just running `grep`, since it uses the default action, `print`.)

Patterns can actually contain two addresses, but it's more typical to use one, as in these cases.  Patterns not enclosed within slashes allow tests like `FNR == 1` (`F`ile-specific `N`umber of this `R`ecord equals `1`) or `NR % 2 == 1` (`N`umber of this `R`ecord—cumulative across all files!—mod `2` equals `1`).

Once you hit the open brace, though, you're into the "action" part.  Now `NR % 2 == 1` simply calculates the result (true or false) and then throws it away.  If you leave out the "pattern" part entirely, the "action" part is run on *every* input line.  So this prints every line.

Note that the test `NR % 2 == 1` is testing the *cumulative* record-number.  So if some file has an odd number of lines ("records"), the next file will print out every *even-numbered* line (and this will persist until you hit another file with an odd number of lines).

For instance, suppose the two input files are `A.txt` and `B.txt`.  Awk starts reading `A.txt` and has both `FNR` and `NR` set to 1 for the first line, which might be, e.g., `file A, line 1`.  Since `FNR == 1` the first "action" is done, setting `o`.  Then awk tests the second pattern.  `NR` is 1, so `NR % 2` is 1, so the second "action" is done, printing that line to `A_oddlines.txt`.

Now suppose file `A.txt` contains only that one line.  Awk now goes on to file `B.txt`, resetting `FNR` but leaving `NR` cumulative.  The first line of `B` might be `file B, line 1`.  Awk tries the first "pattern", and indeed, `FNR == 1` so this closes the old `o` and sets up the new one.

But `NR` is `2`, because `NR` is cumulative across *all* input files.  So the second pattern (`NR % 2 == 1`) computes `2 % 2` (which is `0`) and compares `== 1` which is false, and thus awk skips the second "action" for line 1 of file `B.txt`.  Line 2, if it exists, will have `FNR == 2` and `NR == 3`, so that line will be copied out.

(I originally assumed, since your script was close to working, that you intended this and were just stuck a bit on syntax.)

Comment: thanks it works and I see the error yet I do not really understand it. Would you mind to examplify it. thanks.

Comment: Hi torek, thanks for this excellent explanation. I learned something for the next awk-problem!

Answer (score 3):

With `GNU awk` you could just do:

```
$ awk 'FNR%2{print > (FILENAME".odd")}' *.txt
```

This will create a `.odd` file for every `.txt` file in the current directory containing only the odd lines.

---

However `sed` has the upper hand on conciseness here. The following `GNU sed` command will remove all even lines and store the old file with the extension `.bck` for all `.txt` files in the current directory:

```
$ sed -ni.bck '1~2p' *txt
```

**Demo:**

```
$ ls
f1.txt  f2.txt

$ cat f1.txt
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat f2.txt
6
7
8
9
10

$ sed -ni.bck '1~2p' *txt

$ ls
f1.txt  f1.txt.bck  f2.txt  f2.txt.bck

$ cat f1.txt
1
3
5

$ cat f1.txt.bck
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat f2.txt
6
8
10

$ cat f2.txt.bck
6
7
8
9
10
```

If you don't won't the back up files then simply:

```
$ sed -ni '1~2p' *txt
```

Comment: thanks for the solution with sed. I worked it out with awk, this was just simpler because I already used awk.

Comment: The posted awk script won't select the odd lines from each file, it will select the odd lines across all files. If the first 2 files both have 3 lines, then it'll select lines 1 and 3 from file1 but line 2 from file2. You need to use FNR in the test, not NR. Also, ENDFILE is gawk-specific but if you're using gawk you don't need to close the files as you change files. Finally, you don't need the variable f since you could just do `print > (FILENAME".odd")` but for efficiency you could keep it but only set it when `FNR==1`, I'd do `'FNR==1{if(f)close(f); f=FILENAME".odd"} FNR%2{print > f}'`

Comment: @EdMorton I originally posted `FNR` not sure what I changed it. I do state using `GNU awk` and `gawk` still limits the number of open files right? You don't need a variable but it's good practice, although makes sense to only initialise in `BEGINFILE`.

Comment: No, gawk doesn't limit the number of open files, it magically handles it internally. I know you said GNU awk, I'm just saying that since it's GNU awk you don't need to use ENDFILE and to close the files.

Comment: @EdMorton In that case scratch the file handling.

Comment: Yup, if it's going to be gawk-specific, that's the way to do it. Chances are it'll work with other awks too as long as there's not a huge number of input files. You could also mentioned that with newer gawk versions you can add `-i inedit` to change the original file if that's desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a for loop :

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in dir/*.txt
do    
   oddfile=$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's|\.txt|_odd\.txt|g')  #This will create file_odd.txt
   awk 'NR%2==1' "$file" > "$oddfile"  # This will output it in the same dir.
done
```

Comment: You don't need to escape . in the replacement string and -e and g are redundant `sed 's/[.]txt$/_odd.txt/'`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `NR%2==1` is inside the `{NR%2==1; print>o}` 'action block' and is not kicking in as a 'condition'. Use this instead:

```
gawk 'FNR==1{if(o)close(o);o=FILENAME;sub(/\.txt/,"_oddlines.txt",o)};
     FNR%2==1{print > o}' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It does perfectly the job. But if it looks obvious to you I do not fully understand why the `NR%2==1` must be outside the curly bracket. I thought awk has always a main part with a possible BEGIN and END. It works perfect but does that not leave `NR$2==1` outside one of the parts? Apologies if that looks like a dull question. Thanks.

Comment: @greta, good question. Here's a [basic introduction](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/learning-linux-commands-awk) to how `awk` works, this should get you going with the basic concepts.

Comment: Almost, just change `NR%2` to `FNR%2`.